# Parse.com - Performance problems with 100K users

Tags: parse-platform

We have an a Parse application with about 100K users.

Our queries on the user tables timeout.

For example, I'm doing the following query:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.exists("email");
query.find(...);
```

This query will timeout. If I limit the results to a low number, e.g. 10, I can get the first 10 results. But the next pages will timeout. I.e. this will timeout:

```
query.limit(10);    
query.skip(500);
query.find(...);
```

We are currently at a situation where we are not able to manage our users. Whenever we try to get a list of users by some attribute or change something for a batch of users we get timeout.

We tried doing the queries in cloud code and using the javascript sdk. Both methods fail with timeouts eventually.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a Parse limitation?

Comment: Sounds like it's simply a limitation of your hardware. What hardware are you running the database which contain the user tables?

Comment: @cybermonkey: doesn't Parse run on their own hardware?

Comment: @Thilo Meant the database.

Comment: @cybermonkey Parse.com is a cloud service, and it appears to be that, that is timing out

Comment: @cybermonkey Rowland is correct. Under the covers Parse uses mongodb but I don't have access to the database itself, only the Parse's API.

Comment: If you dont have access to the hardware, I would think about another data structure. Maybe implementing a waiting queue or a cache where you hold answer from queries which are often used in a certain time frame.

Comment: Check out the article with all parse limits.. http://profi.co/all-the-limits-of-parse/

Comment: @style it looks like we're feeling the same pains only you felt them more than a year ago. Although some things have changed, I think Parse is not suitable for tables with lots of records.

Answer (score 0):

Parse cloud functions have a timeout of 15 seconds, and before/after save triggers have a timeout of 3 seconds.

If you need more time, you should find a way to do what you need done in a background job rather than a cloud function. Those have 15 minute timers, which is more than enough to do anything reasonable, and anything that requires more time, you'll have to find a way to save where you left off, and have the function run multiple times until everything you wanted to do is complete.

Comment: Even the simplest query time outs sometime with a 10 records limit on my users table. Therefore I don't think I can use your second solution. Regarding background jobs, they are awkward for my use case. If that's the only solutions then I guess Parse's not suitable for the size of our user base

Comment: What I'm saying is that I'm getting quite tired from doing so many workarounds to get things done :-(